# Open a file in new tab using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Iron PDF to Generate pdf documents from an HTML string. After the file generated i want to open the file in a new tab using ajax call

Here is my ajax post

```
$.post($('#WebSiteUrl').val() + "Print/PrintAsync",
            {
                id: id,
            },
            function (response) {
              window.open(response, '_blank');
                }
            });
```

This won't work.
In the above code, I can return the response as a byte array or FileContentResult.
how can it possible to open as a file in another tab

Answer (score 0):

Simply use get instead of post and return FileContentResult in your asp.net MVC project and open a new tab by javascript like this.

```
window.open($('#WebSiteUrl').val() + "Print/PrintAsync", "_blank");
```

Don't forget to set content type to `application/pdf` when you return FileContentResult.